# Is there a way to add all revert error strings to an ethers js interface?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, error, revert-opcode

According to [this tool](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x08c379a0) if a contract call has a revert message that starts with the signature `0x08c379a0` then the error message is in the format `Error(string)` i.e. a standard revert error `string`(e.g. `revert("error occurred")`), however I cannot add `error Error(string errorString)` to my ethers `Interface` that has a list of custom errors, such that I can parse/decode both those custom errors and standard reverts with a string error messages.

My ethers interface:

```js
import { Interface } from "@ethersproject/abi";

const iErrors = new Interface([
    "error Custom1()",
    "error Custom2()",

    "error Custom3(int errorCode, address account)",
    "error Custom4(int errorCode, uint number)",

    "error AccountLocked(address owner, uint256 balance)",

    // "error Error(string errorString)", // this does not work
]);

const standardErrorString = "0x08c379a0...."; // how to decode this
const accountLockedErrorData = "0xf7c3865a0000000000000000000000008ba1f109551bd432803012645ac136ddd64dba720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000"

const customErrorDescription = iErrors.parseError(customErrorData); // parses AccountLocked error
```

How can I parse/decode both custom error messages and standard revert string messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by first checking if it's a standard revert string and if not attempting to parse it as a custom solidity error.

In addition to `Error(string)` Solidity has another built-in error i.e. `Panic(uint)`, hence I've added a decoding for that as well.

```js
export const parseError = (errorData) => {

    if (errorData.startsWith('0x08c379a0')) { // decode Error(string)

        const content = `0x${errorData.substring(10)}`;
        const reason = utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(["string"], content);

        return reason[0]; // reason: string; for standard revert error string
    }

    if (errorData.startsWith('0x4e487b71')) { // decode Panic(uint)
        const content = `0x${errorData.substring(10)}`;
        const code = utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(["uint"], content);

        return code[0];
    }

    try {
        const errDescription = iErrors.parseError(errorData);
        return errDescription;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```